# Unable to query Flask Backend from React app on Google App Engine

Tags: reactjs, flask, google-app-engine, deployment

I'm trying to have flask and react deployed as separate services on Google App Engine. The flask app is connected to Cloud SQL on GAE. I have a separate yaml file for each. The flask one looks like:

```
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3

network:
  session_affinity: true

handlers:
  # This handler routes all requests not caught above to your main app. It is
  # required when static routes are defined, but can be omitted (along with
  # the entire handlers section) when there are no static files defined.
- url: /(.*)
  script: auto
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
```

and my react one looks like:

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
service: frontend

network:
  session_affinity: true

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

My request from react looks like:

```
      const myRequest = new Request("https://level-landing-320119.ue.r.appspot.com/upsertUser", {
        method: "POST",
        body: myForm,
      });
```

and my backend has something like:

```
@app.route("/upsertUser", methods=["POST"])
def upsert():
```

However, when I run my frontend and click on anything that sends a request to the backend, it fails the console shows

```
websocket connection to wss://frontend-dot-level-landing-320119.ue.r.appspot.com:8080/ws failed.
```

How do I go about debugging this? I'm not sure if the above is the error either. This is my first time working with Google App Engine and I haven't came upon any tutorial on sending requests between services on GAE (instead of hosting only a flask or react app).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you're clicking on a button/link that is for sending stuff to the backend and not taking an action on the front end? I ask because your error mentions the url - ```frontend-dot-level-landing-320119.ue.r.appspot.com:8080/``` which seems to be the url for your front end app. What happens if you click a link that is for your front end - does it work as expected?

Comment: @NoCommandLine if i click a link that navigates in the frontend but does not make calls to the backend, it works as expected. The button also works locally when calling the backend. So far my changes to local has been:
1. make the requirement.txt, app.yaml, and server.yaml files.
2. update my frontend links to call backend (ex. const myRequest = new Request("http://127.0.0.1:5000/history") to (    const myRequest = new Request("https://level-landing-320119.ue.r.appspot.com/history").

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Have you connected with the Cloud SQL from the Flask App correctly? You can refer to [this document](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-flexible) to connect to Cloud SQL from App Engine Flex. Also, can you try to make a request to the backend flask app differently (not from the frontend app) and see if the request goes successfully?